# How to use firebase email auth with react native and react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I am trying to implement firebase authentication in my react native app and am trying to use protected routes in the authentication flow of react navigation. However, even though I have all the functions working (sign in, out etc) I do not know how to save the state in my app (with redux) and use that to change the route in the navigation. If anyone could help out that would be very appreciated.

From the documentation I found I have to use a listener for the persons state:

```
 function checkSignIn(){
  Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
}
```

But I am not sure what to do after

Comment: Your example is incorrect by the way. onAuthStateChanged is a subscription function, expecting a callback. You cannot just return true/false. A workaround would be to return a promise instead and resolve it once the callback was fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with the suggested approach is that when you reload the page, you still don't know the state of the user, so it's rather hard to decide where to redirect or you redirect and then redirect back once the state is "resolved" by firebase.

What I did is that in the top level of my app (the place where I have subscribed to onAuthStateChanged), I've included a state, which specifies if the authentication status is retrieved from firebase. Until it is, I just render a loading animation and once I have the status (being user or null), I can decide where to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You got that right, after the function if user is not null you gan redirect them to home screen and if is null, redirect them to login page:

```
 function checkSignIn(){
     Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
           navigation.navigate("Home")
        } else {
           navigation.navigate("Login")
       }
  })
}
```